# SQL query / data version check

Tags: sql, oracle

I get stuck with some SQL query which check if dateto from first row is not > than datefrom for second row within same ID.Maybe the easiest way is to present it on example:

```
ID     DATEFROM   DATETO     PK
1234   20150512   20150518   1
1234   20150514   20150520   2
1234   20150519   null       3
2313   20150512   20150518   4
44341  20150512   null       5
```

Now, within id 1234 flow is:

```
1.2015-05-12 -> 2015-05-18
2.2015-05-13 -> 2015-05-20  WRONG
3.2015-05-19 -> null
```

In this example end date of first row is > than start date for second row.
As output I would like to display PK id ( in this example:2).

Could anyone give me some hints how to approach this? I don't want SQL but just hints. Thanks in advance

Comment: For your data and rules, (3) should also be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `join` or correlated subquery for this.  I suspect that you want a full overlap comparison:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t.id = t2.id and
                    (t2.start_date < t.start_date and
                     t2.end_date > t.start_date or t2.end_date is null)
             );
```

Comment: You are right, thanks for that, that;s easiest than I thought ; )

Comment: If this worked for you @user5506560 please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  This will help those who follow you.